# AWS SageMaker SKLearn TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, docker, containers, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker to create and deploy a SKLearn estimator (endpoint). I created a `my_file.py` custom script, but when I fit the estimator, in the logs I see:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
where the object is a pandas dataframe obtained by reading a parquet dataset.

If I run the `my_file.py` file locally, the dataset is not set to None.

Here's my SageMaker code:

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.sklearn import SKLearn

my_estimator = SKLearn(entry_point = 'my_file.py',
                       source_dir = 'my_dir',
                       py_version = 'py3',
                       role = sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                       instance_type = '<instance_type>',
                       instance_count = <number_of_instances>,
                       framework_version = '<version>',
                       output_path = 'my_path',
                       base_job_name = 'my_job_name')

# These directories are S3 directories
model_dir = 'my_model_dir'
dataset = 'my_dataset_dir'
file1 = 'my_file1_dir'
empty_dir1 = 'my_empty_dir1'
empty_dir2 = 'my_empty_dir2'
empty_dir3 = 'my_empty_dir3'

my_estimator.fit(inputs = {'dataset': dataset, 
                           'file1': file1, 
                           'emptydir1': empty_dir1, 
                           'emptydir2': empty_dir2,
                           'emptydir3': empty_dir3}, logs = True)
```

And here's my `my_file.py` code:

```
# importing libraries

# defining some functions

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--dataset', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_DATASET'])
    parser.add_argument('--file1', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_FILE1'])
    parser.add_argument('--emptydir1', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_EMPTYDIR1'])
    parser.add_argument('--emptydir2', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_EMPTYDIR2'])
    parser.add_argument('--emptydir3', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_EMPTYDIR3'])
        
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    filename = args.dataset
    dataset = pd.read_parquet(filename)
    print(len(dataset))
    
    # The following line results in the error
    dataset['column1'] = dataset['column1'].astype(str)
    
    # other lines of code
```

Printing the length of the dataset gives me the correct length, so the dataframe is not empty.
Also, the values in the dataframe are neither None nor NaN.

Don't know why I get this error. Any advice?

EDIT

After re-running the fit code some times the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the following code locally with the same dataset.

```
dataset['column1'] = dataset['column1'].astype(str)
```

It seems as if CW is emitting an error specific to this API call/line, it is best to perhaps test this locally first before ingesting into a SageMaker script as this is dependent on the libraries that you are utilizing. You can also use SageMaker local mode to capture these errors early.